# how to assign an array as another array within a class function

Tags: c++, arrays, function, class

this is basically what I am trying to do:

```
class Player
{
public:
    void setInventory(string inventory[]) { this->inventory = inventory; }
private:
    string inventory[4];
};
```

normally I would use `strncpy();` but sadly using the parameter `inventory[]` as the source does not work because it isn't a `const char *`. I want to keep this as an in class function if possible in one or two lines. I just want to know if there is a short way of doing this rather than creating a function outside of the class for it. Thanks

Comment: I recommend you learn about [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array). Or about [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy).

Answer (score 2):

There's [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) if you want copies of the array elements or [`std::move`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move) if you're allowed to move from them.

Example:

```
class Player
{
public:
    void setInventory(std::string inventory[]) {
        std::copy(inventory, inventory + 4, this->inventory);
    }
private:
    std::string inventory[4];
};
```

Note that you should make sure that your "array parameter" (it's a pointer, actually) should've (at least) the required 4 elements. If possible it's better to encode the size into the type, for example using [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

```
struct Player {
  void setInventory(std::array<std::string, 4> i) {
    inventory = i;
  }
  std::array<std::string, 4> inventory;
};
```

This works because `std::array` implements  the assignment operator `operator=`.

Answer (score 0):

You won't use `stdncpy()`, `inventory` is an array of `std::string`, not `char`.

You can write a simple loop to do this,

```
void setInventory(string inventory[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
        this->inventory[i] = inventory[i];
}
```

but the most simple way is to use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

```
class Player
{
public:
    void setInventory(const std::array<std::string, 4>& inventory) { this->inventory = inventory; }
private:
    std::array<std::string, 4> inventory;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should really make your inventory storage into a type or class itself so you can treat it uniformly and clearly.  That would automatically get you copy/move operations (assuming a recent standards-compliant compiler) to keep the handling clear:

```
typedef std::array<std::string, 4> Inventory;

class Player
{
public:
    void setInventory(Inventory &&inventory) {
        this->inventory = inventory;
    }
private:
    Inventory inventory;
};
```

Doing it this way also allows you to expand & enhance `Inventory` itself in the future with zero or minimal refactoring of code that handles it from the outside.